# When will Breeze support ANY filtering (where predicate on children relationship)?

Tags: odata, breeze

We have a need to select records based on the value of a related child table's properties.  I discovered today that this feature is supported in odata with a keyword called 'any'.  Further it's supported in the default breeze server implemention (using entity framework).  Using the same server that my breeze client does, I can enter an odata query in a browser using the 'any' keyword and select records on a related child's field value.  For example:

```
.../Issue?$filter=oIssueImages/any(ii: ii/IssueImageRef eq 4)
```

And it works!  But, there is no support for this in the breezejs client code.

FWIW: I found this breeze feature request: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3988038-adding-any-and-all-filter-operators

Anyone know when breeze will implement this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated post: 11/25/13

As of Breeze 1.4.6, 'any' and 'all' operators are now supported.

So your client side Breeze query would look something like:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Issue")
  .where("oIssueImages", "any", "IssueImageRef", "==", 4);
myEntityManager.executeQuery(query).then(...)
```

Also see: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples

### Older post

Please vote it up.  This is a really good feature, but we really do try to accommodate those features that get the most votes.